# How to restore spinnaker on reboot?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am at my wits end and have been searching everywhere for a solution to this problem but it seems like I am the only one with it.

I have done multiple different methods of spinnaker installs and have tried multiple versions of it but I cannot seem to restore the state of my spinnaker installation after I reboot the machine. I ssh in

```
gcloud compute ssh $HALYARD_HOST     --project=$GCP_PROJECT     -- -L 9000:localhost:9000 -L 8084:localhost:8084
```

I then redirect my browser to the spinnaker UI

```
http://localhost:9000
```

But I get the following showing up on the ssh terminal:

```
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 6: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

It just continues like that as long as I keep the gui open which just sits at the following screen:

[image: spinnaker auth hanging screen]

It sometimes lets me proceed past this point, but then the UI is completely useless. Clicking on different menu options just shows a massive spinner which doesn't go anywhere and everything I did before the reboot is now gone.

[image: useless ui actions]

I have tried the prebaked system provided by google 1-click deploy. I have also tried both the spinnaker computer and container codelabs provided by spinnaker. I have searched a whole host of github questions but no one seems to be running into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR; On Google's kubernetes environment install and configure halyard as root and install your spinnaker instance to the cluster and not the halyard VM.


---


So I figured out the issue. I did not notice that the gcloud ssh command creates a new user on login when I changed workstations. My users at all of my different machines have different usernames (Windows, Linux, Mac, home, office environments)

Secondly, I completed the installation by installing spinnaker directly to the kubernetes cluster from the halyard VM. The halyard installation and configuration I conducted as root.

After trawling a whole log of GitHub questions and answers I noticed that my spinnaker installation was done by the initial user that I logged into the machine as and often I would end up reconnecting to the instance as a different user and end up crying as to why nothing was suddenly working.